# Splitting a text file into individual array elements

Tags: javascript, split, text-files

I've converted a pdf to word to txt file. I'd like to spit every bit of white space including tabs, returns, spaces, etc... so that each individual word, or series of numbers, is it's own array element.  It doesn't seem to work in every case.  What I am trying is...

```
function displayContents(txt) {
    var el = document.getElementById('main'); 
    txt = txt.replace('\t',' ');
    txt = txt.replace('\r',' ');
    txt = txt.replace('\n',' ');
    txt = txt.split(" ");   
    var contents = new Array();

    for(var i in txt) {
        var elem = txt[i];
        var reg = /\d{6}/;
        if (reg.test(elem)) {
            contents.push(elem);
            contents.push("</br>");
        }

    }
    el.innerHTML = contents; //display output in DOM

}
```

What I'm looking for, specifically in this document, are the series of numbers "112345" etc... but I often get results such as "INFORMATION 000100 Hard,".  So, clearly, I'm finding the pieces that include 6 digits, but I'm getting extra stuff.  Looking at the document with ms word and symbols on, these are often spaces, line breaks, or tabs.  but not all spaces are getting split.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: You can split using a regex: `txt=txt.split(/\s/)`, Then add the characters that appear to be missing: `/[\s\u2001]/`

Comment: WOW. That worked so much better than the " ".  thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome, note I have updated my answer.

Comment: Could you post the text file?

Comment: Maybe i wasn't specific enough - and thank you all for your help. BUT, returning 123456 and 123456.00 and 123456.00.00 are all desired, so this particular solution works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(regarding your original code:)
You could split on regex `/\s+/` instead of replacing that list of space-like characters.
Then using `/^\d{6}$/` you'd check if a string contains only 6 digits (from start to end).

Finally filter out your digit-strings that are 6 digits.

Try this example:

```js
function displayContents(txt){
    var contents = new Array()
    ,         el = document.getElementById('main')
    ,          i = 0
    ,          L
    ;
  
    txt=txt.split(/\s+/);   

    for(L=txt.length; i<L; i++){
      /^\d{6}$/.test(txt[i]) && contents.push(txt[i]);
    }

    el.innerHTML = contents.join('<br>') + '<br>';

}
```

```html
<textarea style="width:99%; height:100px" 
       onchange="displayContents(this.value)"
></textarea>
<div id="main"></div>
```

That could be further optimized to just 2 lines of code:

```
function displayContents(txt){
  for(var r=[], L=(txt=txt.split(/\s+/)).length, i=0; i<L; /^\d{6}$/.test(txt[i]) ? r.push(txt[i++]) : i++);
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML=r.join('<br>') + '<br>';
}
```

---

Alternatively you could `match` out all sequences of 6 digits using `/\s\d{6}(?=\s)/g`.
This will match all occurrences of a space-character + 6 digits (followed by a space-char, not included in the match).

Note that we do *not* use `/\d{6}/g` because that would also match `123456` in `1234567`!!
Note that we also do not use `/\D\d{6}(?=\D)/g` as that would match `123456` in `x123456y`!!

```js
function displayContents(txt){
  for( var L=(txt=(' '+txt+' ').match(/\s\d{6}(?=\s)/g)).length
     ; L--
     ; txt[L]=txt[L].slice(1)  //removing first non-digit character.
     );
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML=txt.join('<br>') + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<textarea style="width:99%; height:100px" 
       onchange="displayContents(this.value)"
></textarea>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `/\s\d{6}\s/g`. This will find all numbers that have 6 digits in a row that are surrounded by a space.

Comment: `/\d{6}/g` includes `123456` in `1234567`

Comment: @GitaarLAB, he stated that he was trying to match the 6 digit numbers.

Comment: His current code splits on spaces, giving isolated numbers. If one of those numbers (strings) is `1234567` then it will match `123456`

Comment: Yes, I understand.  That's what he wants, I think . . .

Comment: Lol, it always boils down to interpretation `:)` My interpretation is that he wants only isolated number(strings) that are 6 digits.

Comment: @GitaarLAB, Ahhhhh, I see what you mean.  Editing answer now.

Comment: That's what I have in my answer `:)`, but now he has results like `\s123456\s`. Also it would miss `123456` in `123456 asdf`, so he would need to do `' '+txt+' '` (I also have that covered in my answer).